# Does "int ** myArray[height][width]" create a 2D array of size height and width?

Tags: c

Does `int **myArray[height][width]` create a 2D array of size height and width?

```
type arrayName [ x ][ y ]; //creates a 2D array
```

I would like to create a 2D array and then be able to interact with it using `type** arrayName`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: No, that’s a 2D array of `int **`.  IOW, each `myArray[i][j]` is an `int **`.

Comment: @JohnBode, great catch. Clockwise spiral rule slipped the mind, so you have an array of `height` x `width` *pointer-to-pointer-to* `int` (that's a whole lot more the other way around `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to initialize a 2D array:

```
int main()
{
    int height = 10, width = 10, i = 0;
    int **array = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int) * height);
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * width);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

and you can access them as:

```
array[i][j]
```

Comment: Thanks, Criss. Does int ** myArray[height][width] create an array or just a pointer to a pointer to a 2D array of ints?

Comment: A single *pointer* to *pointer(s)* to `int[height][width]`. Suggest `int **array = malloc (height * sizeof *array);` and then `array[i] = malloc (width * sizeof *array[i]);` If you set type-size using the dereferenced pointer -- you will never get it wrong, and see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) (always validate EVERY allocation)

Comment: No no no, `int **myArray[height][width]` is a 2D array of `int **`.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. `int ** arrayName [ x ][ y ];` creates a 2D array of pointers to pointers to int.
This is because the brackets are a way of saying “make this an array with size x”. The asterisk is saying make this a pointer, which is another way of saying “make this an array of unknown size”.

What you want is `int arr [height][width]`.
I’m unsure what you mean by how you want to interact with this array.
You can interact with `arr` by using brackets.

`int row[width] = arr[column]`  will give you a row at index `column`  and `int cell = row[x]`  will give you the cell of that row at index x.

Comment: I've got a function with "struct Pixel ** pArr" as a parameter to a function. That function will be responsible for filling this 2-D array. Due to the fact that pArr is a pointer to a pointer of an array of struct Pixel's I thought that can't use bracket notation...

Comment: pArr is actually a “pointer to pointer to a struct Pixel” or equally “a 2D array of unknown size of struct Pixels”. You can access the elements using brackets. Arrays are just fancy pointers. But when you access it you have to be careful. If your array has two elements and you try to access the this element youre in trouble.

Comment: That's it! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

```
int **myArray[height][width];
```

creates `myArray` as a 2D array of `int **`; IOW, each `myArray[i][j]` has type `int **`.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

Given an array declaration

```
int a[N];
```

the *expression* `a` will "decay" from type "N-element array of `int`" (`int [N]`) to type "pointer to `int`" (`int *`) and the value of the expression will be `&a[0]`.

Given a 2D array declaration

```
int a2[N][M];
```

the expression `a2` will "decay" from type "N-element array of M-element array of `int`" (`int [N][M]`) to type "pointer to *M-element array of `int`*" (`int (*)[M]`), not "pointer to pointer to `int`" (`int **`).

IOW, an `int **` is not a 2D array - it’s a pointer to a pointer.  That pointer may point to the first in a *sequence* of pointers, each of which may point to the first in a sequence of `int`:

```
         int **    int *                int
         +–––+     +–––+                +–––+
myArray: |   | ––> |   | myArray[0] ––> |   | myArray[0][0]
         +–––+     +–––+                +–––+
                   |   | myArray[1] –+  |   | myArray[0][1]
                   +–––+             |  +–––+
                    ...              |   ...
                                     |  +–––+
                                     +> |   | myArray[1][0]
                                        +–––+
                                        |   | myArray[1][1]
                                        +–––+
```

There are a couple of ways to build this structure.  You could declare a bunch of 1D arrays (potentially of different lengths) and define `myArray` as a 1D array of `int *`:

```
int foo[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int bar[] = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int baz[] = { 3, 5, 7, 11 };

int *myArray[] = { foo, bar, baz };
```

The expression "myArray" will decay from type "3-element array of `int *`" (`int *[3]`) to "pointer to `int *`" (`int **`).

Alternately, you could declare `myArray` as an `int **` and allocate the memory like so:

```
int **myArray = malloc( sizeof *myArray * height ); // sizeof *myArray == sizeof (int *)

for( size_t i = 0; i < width; i++ )
  myArray[i] = malloc( sizeof *myArray[i] * width ); // sizeof *myArray[i] == sizeof (int)
```

You will want to add some error checking to make sure each `malloc` call succeed, and if any fail you will want to roll back any previous allocations before erroring out.

Be aware that unlike a "true" 2D array, the rows of this structure will not be contiguous in memory.  You won’t be able to do bulk copies or writes of this structure by just providing the base address and the size.